# How to clear existing routes and push new routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, durandal, hottowel

I use the following in Hot Towel SPA template for ASP.net MVC

```
 router.mapNav('home');
 router.mapNav('register');
 router.mapNav('login');
```

I wanted to clear the existing routes and push my new values.

```
 router.mapNav('Career');
 router.mapNav('Contact');
```

How do I achieve this in my project?

I am trying to achieve a functionality to set new nav bars after some authentication check.

Comment: Anybody have answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to check following discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/durandaljs/jXMFG1I6PVw

Comment: I found that reference Helpful and answering my question based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more information based on the discussion happened in the link https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/durandaljs/jXMFG1I6PVw ,I have added deactivate function in router.js. Find the detailed answer below.

```
deactivate: function () {
    router.allRoutes.removeAll();
    router.visibleRoutes.removeAll();
    if (sammy) {
        sammy.destroy();
    }
}
```